¿Existe la palabra chorero con el significado de aquel que roba?
En México existe la palabrar choreo como:

Chorear es un verbo que algunos mexicanos (particularmente los
capitalinos) usan para referirse a una forma de comunicación de ideas
o información que no es concisa.

Que es chorear
Y también la palabra chorero,

m. y f. Persona que chorea.

Chorero
Entiendo que este chorero se aplica a la persona que chorea en este primer significado mencionado de la palabra.
Pero en otras partes de latinoamérica chorear es robar

tr. coloq. Arg., Chile y Perú. robar (‖ tomar para sí o hurtar).

RAE chorear
Aquí en Argentina al que chorea (roba), se le dice chorro, no chorero.
Pero tal vez sea válido también decirle chorero? Ya que para la misma palabra (chorear) pero con otro significado, aquel que chorea, es chorero.
¿Se puede decir la palabra chorero con el significado de aquel que roba?

¿Se puede decir la palabra "chorero" con el significado de aquel que roba?
Si, además del uso consignado en México, en otros países de LatinoAmérica se usa chorero como sinónimo de chorro (ladrón).
Probablemente no se lo use o conozca en el Río de la Plata o en las provincias del centro de Argentina, pero si puedo dar fe de que es de uso común en Tucumán y otras provincias vecinas del NOA.
Asimismo se encuentra esa palabra para designar lo mismo en Perú, tal como refiere esta entrada en Google Books sobre la jerga o argot limeño con el sentido ántes consignado.

Desconozco si en Chile signifique además lo mismo, por cuanto esta entrada de un diccionario de términos de ese país ("Chilangonario", diccionario de palabras usadas en Chile) incluye al término chorero con un sentido de estafador de la confianza,  de embaucador, que engaña y envuelve con palabras
